# Closest language to Python's syntax that is more low level language!

Tags: python, programming-languages, syntax, low-level

I guess topic says it all! But, I really wan't a syntax similar to Python's! And low-level... like C++ for example. I guess Java and C# is OK too, but I really have a huge problem with the { }, and always ; <-- and each line. I hate it so much...

Comment: Well, assembly is more low-level, and it doesn't have semicolons...

Comment: Why don't you like braces or semicolons?  I find them incredibly useful in making the code easier to understand and read.

Comment: Honestly: your 'huge problem' with the {} will go away as soon as you use C/C++/Java/C# more frequently. Its just syntactic sugar how source code is structured, nothing more. You shouldn't choose the programming language you use basing on a few evil symbols in its syntax. Choose it depending on the features/requirements you need for a particular project.

Comment: Wow that's the exact opposite of how I feel.  I think `{}` and `;` make my life so much easier.  Maybe I'm just a luddite, who knows?

Comment: It's surprising to me that you would pick a language based on syntax. That's what editor's are for. Also, not sure you really mean more low-level, since Python can do almost anything (given extensions). What do you really mean? Compiled? Faster?

Comment: It's not just the useless semicolons.  It's things like `for x in [1, 3, 4]:`, `if x in ['cat', 'hat', 'bat']:`, buffer overflows, etc.  C is tedious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Cython](http://www.cython.org/) is a lower-level language with a syntax similar to Python's.

Answer (score 15):

[cython](http://www.cython.org/) may be pretty close to what you want: syntax just about identical to Python, and you can basically write C-level code in it.  It's tuned to generate Python-usable extensions, but you could then "freeze" them into a stand-alone executable.

[boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) is another language with very Python-like syntax, and semantics to about the level of C# (also .NET oriented, but there's a JVM-oriented version in the works, I hear).

Answer (score 6):

[Cobra](http://cobra-language.com/) compiles to C#. Variables get typed after their first usage. Performance is about the same as C#.

Answer (score 3):

Google's [Go](http://golang.org/) language was designed with Python syntax in mind though its got a hell of a lot of C in its genes too.

Comment: Go does have curly braces and I believe semicolons (they are present in the tutorial, even if not in any of the given examples --are they optional?)

Answer (score 0):

[Genie](http://live.gnome.org/Genie) could be what you are looking for. Is a python-like language (at least no semicolons) that compiles to c.